# Calculating leap years

Tags: python

I have an assignment that is supposed to calculate whether a year that the user inputs is in fact a leap year. I cannot figure out the formula for this. Can anyone help? I can figure out the rest of the code but here is what is needed:

**The month of February normally has 28 days. But if it is a leap year, February has 29 days.
Write a program that asks the user to enter a year. The program should then display the
number of days in February that year. Use the following criteria to identify leap years:
1. Determine whether the year is divisible by 100. If it is, then it is a leap year if and only
if it is also divisible by 400. For example, 2000 is a leap year, but 2100 is not.
2. If the year is not divisible by 100, then it is a leap year if and only if it is divisible by 4.
For example, 2008 is a leap year, but 2009 is not.**

Comment: ```if else if else if else``` is your answer. The answer you need is in the problem, please read it carefully. We should not be doing your homework for you.

Comment: If your problem is not programming but figuring out the formula, SO is probably not the right place.

Comment: You can figure out the rest of the code? Post what you have figured out then.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/leap-year

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @RedCricket Be careful; that's how classmates get code to copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from calendar import isleap
year=input('Year: ')
if isleap(int(year)):
   print(29)
else:
   print(28)
```

Or without import:

```
year=input('Year: ')
if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
    print(29)
else:
    print(28)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The month of February normally has 28 days. But if it is a leap year, February has 29 days. Write a program that asks the user to enter a year. The program should then display the number of days in February that year. Use the following criteria to identify leap years...

The assignment contains the logic/steps in prose; write the steps in comments and then convert the comments to code.

I've done the first bit below, including the relevant "comment instructions". Now write the code below each comment. Among other things, the code should contain `if/then/else` and use the `%` (modulus) operator.

```
# 1. Determine whether the year is divisible by 100.
# If it is, then it is a leap year if and only if it is also divisible by 400 [otherwise it is not a leap year]

# 2. [otherwise, ] If the year is not divisible by 100,
# then it is a leap year if and only if it is divisible by 4 [otherwise it is not a leap year]
```

To structure code cleaner, consider putting the comments/logic inside a function:

```
def is_leapyear (year):
    # comments and logic here
    # and 'return' true or false

# call is_leapyear in main program, supplying the year to test
```

Coding takes *a lot* of practice .. so practice :)

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. I see now that the percent is a remainder symbol. So when divided ( year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 ==0) as well as the initial division by 4, the answer is true as long as there are no remainders. I was curious as to how I could manage coming to a number being divisible to be true in an equation. I was not trying to get anyone to do it for me, however this has been a major step in helping me to understand an operand I have never used before

Comment: @dizzL You may also want to look at [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod).

Comment: @RedCricket I simply hadn't used the modulus before as I am just learning in the first couple of chapters. I have done plenty of coding the past few hours for other examples and this one had me stumped.

Comment: @user2864740 Tank you for your help. although I understood the instructions, I could not translate to code as far as finding out a way to use dividends without remainders

Comment: @leewz Thanks! Good to know more built-in methods

Comment: @U9-Forward  Thank you very much for your help